# AndEngine scene load resources

Tags: android, layer, andengine, scene

Help me please, wat's wrong in my code? On device shown black background.

```
public void onLoadResources()
{

    this.mTexture = new Texture(1024, 1024);
    this.mTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/bgr.png",0,0);
    this.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene()
{
    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
    backLayer=new Sprite(0,0,this.mTextureRegion);  
    scene.getTopLayer().addEntity(backLayer);
    return scene;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest going to the [AndEngine forums](http://www.andengine.org/forums) and looking through some of the Tutorials and the Examples.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few fixes for you:

1. Don't use the constructor `Scene(int)`, its **deprecated**. Use `Scene()` instead.
2. By your sprite's name, I guess it is your scene background? If this is your intention, you should use this: `scene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(backLayer));`, instead of `scene.getTopLayer().addEntity(backLayer);`.
3. Lastly, I didn't see the method `createFromAsset` in `TextureRegionFactory`. Maybe you should update your AndEngine classes? And try this instead, might work:

   ```
   BitmapTextureAtlas textureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
   BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");    
   this.mTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(textureAtlas, this, "bgr.png", 0, 0);
   ```